# Virtual/dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu on one harddisk and Windows 7 Home Premium on another. I made absolutely certain they're completely separate, so I have to actively choose to boot from Windows' disk if I want to run it. This is working well.

But now I would like to run Ubuntu as a VM with VirtualBox while running Windows. That is to say, I'll create a VM with direct access to Ubuntus disk. I've done this once before, but then I did the reverse; running Windows as a VM and as a host. That ended up very badly. Ubuntu, however, shouldn't have any problems being run like this, should it? I mean, there's no chance the disk will be used by both operating systems at the same time in any case. But what about drivers and such? It's probably AMDs display driver I'm most worried about.

Is there anything I need to worry about here?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, no, Ubuntu will run just fine as a VM with direct disk access. You will have to install Guest Addition for enhanced graphical performance, and assign enough video memory and enable 3D acceleration for all the eye candy of Unity. Guest Additions will not be used when you boot physically; similarly, the AMD drivers won't be used by the VM but will be ready when you boot physically.

Comment: I was actually unable to boot Ubuntu directly after installing vbox guest additions. I had to remove them. The problem went away all by itself, though, since Windows 7 Home Premium only lasted two days. Now it boots directly to bliescreen. :)